# Switch in horizontal LinearLayout causes miscalculated height

Tags: android, switch-statement, android-linearlayout

Here is a simple horizontal LinearLayout with a textview and a switch.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Change the visibility of the below Switch to experiment the height measurement." />

    <Switch
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The render of this layout is problematic. As you can see below, textview is being cropped and linear layout cannot wrap it's content.

[image: switch bug]

When I remove the switch this problem disappears.

Anyone has ever experienced this issue? Is this a bug?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No need to be worry, once you will run it on real device it works perfectly :)

Comment: @shahid17june  To my surprise, it will not happen. Seems like a bug to me, but I need to have a better look

Comment: Can you post your all the Xml code here?

Comment: Just place the above code in a `RelativeLayout` and you can start wondering why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Is it you wanted to archive.?

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true">

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/switch"
                    android:text="Change the visibility of the below Switch to experiment the height measurement."/>

            <Switch
                    android:id="@+id/switch"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:visibility="visible"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I know that I can get a proper layout using Relative Layout. However my question is why the linear layout behaves differently?